# How in Coq to make `simpl` command perform only one step reduction?

Tags: logic, coq, induction

My definition of add is as follows:

```
Fixpoint add n m :=
  match n with
  | 0 => m
  | S p => add p (S m)
end.
```

Later in the file I am trying to prove the following goal:
`add (S n) 0 = S n`

I call `simpl` command expecting it to reduce

`add (S n) 0` to `add n (S 0)`.

Instead it reduces

`add (S n) 0` to `add n 1`

I suspect `simpl` command executes multiple steps as long as it can execute.

**My question**: is there a command that would make a one step reduction, reducing

```
add (S n) 0 = S n
```

to

```
add n (S 0) = S n
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`S 0` and `1` are the same expressions.

"Same" doesn't only mean `S 0 = 1` holds, but the coq's system cannot distinguish them. In contrast,  `1 + 0` and `1` are not the same while `1 + 0 =  1` holds.

`0` is a Notation for `O`, and `1` is a Notation for `S O`.
So both `S 0` and `1` represent the same expression `S O`.

If you start to prove `S 0 = 1`, you will immediately see the goal is `1 = 1`, or `eq (S O) (S O)` if you disable Notations by `Unset Printing Notations`.